# Automate Saving for iPhone images in Photoshop

Tags: ios, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a dream script I'm looking for and wondering if anyone here as stumbled across one

Problem: Creating @2x and regular PNG files for iOS software

> Edit: no need to worry about file type. iOS images should ALWAYS be 24bit PNG

In my workflow, I'll get my image all set then go through this same exact ritual every time:

1. Save for Web & Devices
2. Press Save and choose a filename, like "myimage@2x.png"
3. Save for Web & Devices again
4. Reduce image size by 50%
5. Press Save and choose a similar filename like "myimage.png"

My dream photoshop script would
1. Ask for a filename & location: i.e. present a typical save dialog
2. I'd enter a name "myimage"
3. it would save the current document as "myimage@2x" in that location, and then save a 50% reduced image named "myimage" also in that location

Any ideas?  I've poked around the photoshop scripting reference but its a bit overwhelming.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an action set I created (JLRetinaPNGExport.atn) which you can find [here](http://jlabs.me/public/JLRetinaPNGExport.atn). This action set comes with 3 actions:

1. current layer export as .png at 100% then 50%
2. current layer, trim transparent pixels, then export as .png at 100% then 50%
3. merge visible and export as .png at 100% then 50%

This action set was modified from this [action set](http://uncorkedstudios.com/2013/01/19/best-photoshop-export-action-ever/). Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you upload your file again please ? The link seems to be broken.

Comment: Link updated. Also added another action which is "current layer, trim, then export as .png at 100% then 50%"

Comment: Hi, link is broken again. please, upload it again.(or give me a file, and i'll share it via github)

Comment: This action not save automatically names. It will be great to make auto saving @2x postfix. Is it possible to be done?

Comment: Link down again. Can you please recheck.

Answer (score 3):

You could use photoshop Actions for that. You can found dozens of how-tos for that in google.

But i rather prefer to save all images just in retina with @2x and then load them all in the little and smart app called unretiner ([Appstore link](http://itunes.apple.com/at/app/unretiner/id411277085?mt=12)) to generate the lowers images.

Comment: For Actions, you can't customize the file name it uses to Save. It would be nice if I could set the name once, and it removes (or adds) @2x when it does the saving.  I also have a script to convert but it would be much more convenient to do it all in one action inside Photoshop

Comment: But you can run Photoshop scripts with Actions, and photoshop scripts are amazing. Take a look at the linked site[1] of adobe about scripting. In ps scripts you can do all that naming stuff and a lot of more. I already had to use it to add prefixes and suffixes to the filename and save. It took some time to learn it, but if you already speak javascript it should be easy.


  [1]: http://But%20you%20can%20run%20Photoshop%20scripts%20with%20Actions,%20and%20photoshop%20scripts%20are%20amazing.%20http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html